# How to write a query with two requirements in overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to retrieve a bus route for specific bus services. How do I include two key in overpass query such that I could find the bus routes of specific bus services? For example, I would like to find the bus routes of bus Svc 3 ?

How do I include two features:

"route" = "bus"

"name" = "Svc 3"

**QUERY**

```
node["route"="bus",](around:{{radius}},{{geocodeCoords:'country'}});
way["route"="bus"](around:{{radius}},{{geocodeCoords:'country'}});
relation["route"="bus"](around:{{radius}},{{geocodeCoords:'country'}});
```

Comment: hello Denise - good day: thanks for raising this question: some ideas & ressources you may find useful : https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-https://pypi.org/project/overpass/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568555/python-wrapper-to-run-requests-on-the-endpoint-of-overpass-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation of the query statement](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#The_Query_Statement). To specify multiple filters just add them one after the other:

```
relation["route"="bus"]["name"="Svc 3"](around:{{radius}},{{geocodeCoords:'country'}});
```